# Android Network Service Discovery with Ipv6

Tags: java, android, sockets, ipv6, nsd

I have develop a new android app. This app creates a HotSpot networks and a service. But There is a problem. In client side of network discovery service resolve IPv6 adress of my android app so the client can not connect to my service via tcp socket.

My questions are

1. Is there a way send IPv4 adress to network service discovery clients?
2. Or Is there a way create a socket connection with Ipv6 adress in client side?

Note : My android device version are above Android 5.0.1

Comment: TCP works with IPv6, too.

Comment: But when I connect the socket I get this error "java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /fe80::5427:58ff:fec3:f11a (port 43234): connect failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)"

Comment: You must have IPv6 enabled on both sides of the connection.

Comment: How can I do this in Android? Is there a example?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic on [so].

Comment: Ok. Do you have an example code or something else?

Comment: You must use the scope ID when connecting to link-local addresses. For example `fe80::5427:58ff:fec3:f11a%wlan0`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHampton , your answer is correct. I can connect now.